# how python handle with circle on GC?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I know that python uses *reference counting* for garbage collection.

Every object that is allocated on the heap has counter that counts the number of object that refer to it, when the counter hits zero, the object is delete.

but how python handle with circle pointer?

if one of then delete the second stay with 1 counter but need to be delete.

Comment: AFAIK Python has an additional and optional garbage collector (that is by default turned on) that every now and then checks if objects are references from the "active set" of variables (by inspecting the call stack).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
i want more detail about it , that call mark and weep?

Comment: Have a look here https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-in-Python-work

Comment: @Jonas `Main Ideas of CPython’s Garbage Collector` .. i need on `python` not `cpython`

Comment: @JONI6543: CPython is the standard implementation of Python. Different implementations have completely different garbage collection schemes; most of them don't even have reference counting at all.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is handled is dependent on the python implementation. The reference implementation, the one you're probably using, is sometimes called CPython, because it is written in C.

CPython uses reference counting to clean up object which are obviously no longer used. However, every once in a while, it pauses execution of the program, and begins will the objects directly referenced by variables alive in the program. Then, it follows all references as long as it can, marking which objects have been visited. Once it has followed all references, it finds all the objects which aren't reachable from the main program, and deletes them. This is called tracing garbage collection, of which mark and sweep is a particular implementation.

If you want, and you're sure your program has no circular references, you can turn this feature off to improve performance. If you have circular references, however, you'll accidentally cause memory leaks, so it's usually not worth doing unless you're really worried about performance.

Comment: Python's GC actually doesn't start from known-reachable objects, because its reference management system can't identify the root set of references to start the traversal from. Instead, it has to account for all references it knows about to figure out which tracked objects have references it doesn't know about, then start the traversal from those objects.

Comment: You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/93260281159844908bd988e5286bd5372f012cf3/Modules/gcmodule.c#L906), and an outdated but still mostly accurate overview [here](http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/).